# Label control does not update its text value from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

In the following code you can see an AjaxFileUpload control and a Label inside a UpdatePanel. The intended behaviour is to change the lb_Info.Text value to show info in case an error ocurred during the upload.

.aspx file

```
<asp:Panel id="IP_Modal" runat="server" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="form-inline">

  <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="fup_Main" runat="server" 
     OnUploadComplete="UploadButton_Click"
     OnClientUploadComplete="MyNamespace.UploadComplete"
     OnClientUploadError="MyNamespace.UploadComplete"
     MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" />

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="IP_UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lb_Info" runat="server" Text="Dummy Text"/>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fup_Main" EventName="UploadComplete"/>
     </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

  //Some hidden <asp:LinkButtons /> are here
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Here you can see the C# function that is executed when the event OnUploadComplete is fired.
.cs file

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{            
   try
   {            
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
     if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("some_dir_path")))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("some_dir_path"));

     fup_Main.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("some_dir_path" + filename);

     /* Some validations here */

     lb_Info.Text = "Text from code-behind";
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      lb_Info.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

When i run this code, i can perfectly select and upload a file using the AjaxFileUpload control, when the upload its completed the "OnUploadComplete" event fires and the "UploadButton_Click" function is executed, but the page is not updated with the new label text.

I thought that the error could be in the EventName property of the Triggers section, BUT if i use EventName="OnUploadComplete" (which is the property name in the AjaxFileUpload control) the page doesn't even render with the message "Could not find an event named 'OnUploadComplete' on associated control 'fup_Main' for the trigger in UpdatePanel"

Any idea of what am i missing here?
Thank you in advance for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the end of UploadButton_Click method (can be in finally block after try catch):

```
IP_UpdatePanel.Update();
```

Comment: Already tried this and it does not solve the issue, the label in the UpdatePanel still shows the initial text.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me : Kindly apply on your code : Code  Tested

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">
    function AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete() {
        console.log('<%#myThrobber.ClientID%>');
        document.getElementById('myThrobber').innerHTML = "File Uploaded    Successfully";}
   </script>



   ![enter image description here][1]<div>

    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
     OnClientUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"   ThrobberID="myThrobber" 
        MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" Width="337px" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myThrobber"  ></asp:Label>
</div>


Code Behind : 

protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = @"D:\Manish\FirstProject\sampleproject\sampleproject\upload\" + e.FileName;


        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);


    }
```

I don;t know why it is not working from server side :(

Comment: Also tried this with no luck. Since the default event of the AjaxFileUpload control is "UploadComplete" we doesnt have to specify the event, but the behaviour is the same :S

Comment: I just tried that by inserting this code in the c#: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "TestScript", "MainContent_lb_Info.innerHTML = 'TEST_TEXT'", true); (the MainContent_ prefix is because the browser name the control that way) and is not working, BUT, it works if i execute it from the js console in chrome :S